# multiple upload php

Tags: php, html

Im stuck on a problem,

I have created a multiply uploader, it works fine until i want the file I upload to register the name inside a database, 
The error message I get is

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given in C:\wamp\www\bookstyled\profile.php on line 16

My line 16 is the variable file_name

```
$file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file_name']['name']);
```

If I remove the mysql_real_escape_string, It actually save to the database but not as the file name, but its says " Array "

This is some of the code

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_name'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['file_name'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

$file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file_name']['name']);


$dt1=date('y-m-d H:m:s');
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` (`file_name`, `user_name`,`file_time`,`file_ip`) VALUES ('$file_name', '{$_SESSION['username']}','$dt1','$ip')") ; 
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "core/files/{$_FILES['file_name']['name'][$key]}");
}
}
```

And If I didn't mention it 
The files are being upload.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enabled multiple uploads. So I'm guessing your html names for the fields are arrays. eg:

```
<input type="file" name="file_name[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Now $_FILES['file_name']['name'] doesn't hold one file but multiple files in an array.

Each file is individually accessed through

```
$_FILES['file_name']['name'][$i] //where $i is a 0,1,2.....
```

Since you are using

```
$file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file_name']['name'])
```

the function mysql_real_escape_string isn't being given a string as the parameter but the complete array which hold each and every file uploaded to 'file_name'.

The solutions is simple, you need to use

```
file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file_name']['name'][$key])
```

$key because I see that you are already using that in move_upload_file function

Comment: Thank you! Its been nagging me the hole day :)

Thanks

Comment: Same answer than mine, but more explanatory. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you change this

```
$file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file_name']['name']);
```

to this

```
$file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file_name']['name'][$key]);
```

As you use this `[$key]` in this sentence `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "core/files/{$_FILES['file_name']['name'][$key]}");` I think you should use on the line 16 too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like $_FILES['file_name']['name'] is an array as opposed to a string, so try $_FILES['file_name']['name']['key']

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but could work.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_name'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['file_name'] as $file){

       $file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($file['tmp_name']);


       $dt1=date('y-m-d H:m:s');
       $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` (`file_name`, `user_name`,`file_time`,`file_ip`) VALUES ('$file_name', '{$_SESSION['username']}','$dt1','$ip')") ; 
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "core/files/{$file['name']}");
    }
}
```